# Como juntar tres consultas pero de una misma Tabla en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera saber si se puede juntar tres tablas pero con distintas condiciones, un resultado alado del otro.

> ----Primera Consulta ----

```
--Atenciones Emergencia
    select  
    year(fecha)*100+month(fecha) as Periodo, 
    NombreMedicoAtencion as Medico ,
    TipoAtencionNombre, 
    count(distinct CodigoOA) as Atenc_Emer 
    from TBL_QV_Hecho_Produccion_IF
    where 
    year(fecha)>=2018 
    and CodigoSucursal='ceg' 
    and GrupoProduccion='Consultas' 
    and IdTipoAtencion=2
    group by year(fecha)*100+month(fecha), NombreMedicoAtencion ,TipoAtencionNombre
    order by  Medico, Periodo
```

> ----Segunda Consulta----

```
--Consultorio Externo
select 
year(fecha)*100+month(fecha) as Periodo,
NombreMedicoAtencion as Medico,
TipoAtencionNombre, 
sum(cantidad) as Atenc_Amb from TBL_QV_Hecho_Produccion_IF
where 
year(fecha)>=2016 
and CodigoSucursal='ceg' 
and GrupoProduccion='Consultas' 
and IdTipoAtencion=1
group by year(fecha)*100+month(fecha),NombreMedicoAtencion, TipoAtencionNombre
order by  Medico, Periodo
```

> ----Tercera Consulta ----

```
   ----Egresos hospitalario
    select 
    year(fecha)*100+month(fecha) as Periodo, 
    IdMedicoAtencion ,
    NombreMedicoAtencion as Medico, 
    count(distinct CodigoOA) as Egresos 
    from TBL_QV_Hecho_Produccion_IF
    where 
    year(fecha)>=2016 
    and CodigoSucursal='ceg' 
    and IdTipoAtencion=3 
    and NombreEstadoDocumento<>'anulado' 
    and GrupoProduccion='hospitalizacion'
    group by year(fecha)*100+month(fecha), NombreMedicoAtencion
    order by  Medico, Periodo
```

---

Como ven son tres consultas con diferentes condiciones lo que estaba intentando era tener

Solo los encabezados

PERIODO 
MEDICO 
COUNT(Distinct CodigoOA) ----> de la primera consulta
Sum(Cantidades) -----> de la segunda consulta
COUNT(Distinct CodigoOA) -----> de la tercera consulta

el objetivo es tener a todos los médicos pero por cantidades de sus servicios.

[image: Estes es el resultado que quiero llegar]

Answer (score 3):

Puedes tratar de hacer las consultas en la misma ya que usas los mismos datos solo haciendo un count o sum diferente y eso te lo arreglas con el where donde pones que lleve los 3 tipos de Atención.

Alli obtienes una consulta general para los 3 campos pudiendo ser cualquier tipo de atención.

```
select  
year(fecha)*100+month(fecha) as Periodo, 
NombreMedicoAtencion as Medico ,
TipoAtencionNombre, 
count(distinct CodigoOA) as Atenc_Emer,
sum(cantidad) as Atenc_Amb,
count(distinct CodigoOA) as Egresos 
from TBL_QV_Hecho_Produccion_IF
where 
year(fecha)>=2018 
and CodigoSucursal='ceg' 
and GrupoProduccion='Consultas' 
and IdTipoAtencion IN ('1','2','3')
group by year(fecha)*100+month(fecha), NombreMedicoAtencion ,TipoAtencionNombre
order by  Medico, Periodo
```

Comment: Respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, dale a editar y explica tu respuesta

Comment: hecho, lo siento lo hacia mientras me corregías muchas gracias.

Comment: @LuisM.López el codigo que meque me das como respuesta meda datos todos iguales ya que si ves por cada consulta sus condiciones son diferentes, por ejemplo me esta diciendo que un medico tiene 134 consultas ambulatorias, 134 consultas de emergencia y hospitalarias en un solo mes algo que no es así.